# Docker renaming network interfaces

Tags: networking, docker, ip-address

I am trying to rename the network interfaces inside a docker container.

Right now they are `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`, etc. I would like them to have different names. I know how to do it in Ubuntu with modifying the `70-persistent-rules` file, but that file seems to be missing.

I had to use docker commands to change the ip addresses, so I was wondering if there was a docker command for this as well. The docker container I am using is an ubuntu 14.04

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

I ran my container in privileged mode with the below command:

```
docker run -i -t \
    --name #NAME# \
    --privileged \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /dev:/host/dev \
    -v /proc:/host/proc:ro \
    -v /boot:/host/boot:ro \
    -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro \
    -v /usr:/host/usr:ro container:latest
```

Replace `#NAME#` with what you want the name to be and replace `container:latest` with your container.

With this, I was able to change the ip address name with ifconfig.